# Draw all textures flipped?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, drawing, textures

First off, with my background in XNA i just cannot get used to the inverted Y axis. So in LibGDX i flipped the `OrthographicCamera` with `cam.setToOrtho(true,width, height)` but this obviously ends up in drawing all my textures upside down.

I can create `Sprites` and `TextureRegions` from all my textures to flip each and every one of them but that takes a lot of extra code. So is there a efficient way to have all my textures flipped around there center?

I tried adding a flipped matrix to the `spritebatch` `transformMatrix` but that cancels out the flipped ortho cam. I also tried to create a `Sprite` for drawing all my textures and flips them but without success.

Comment: Why not just get used to inverted Y? Seems silly to do all this extra work

Comment: @redFIVE Yeah, i tried but i always end up walking through my code and fix things involving this.

Comment: You are just making your code more complicated for anyone who may want to maintain your code in the future

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can probably just use [flip](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/TextureRegion.html#flip-boolean-boolean-), like so.

```
textureRegion.flip(false, true);
```

for every `TextureRegion` you have.

Since `Sprites` extend `TextureRegions`, this should work for them too

Comment: I currently just use Texture and use that straight inside the spritebatch.draw method. So this does add some extra work, isn't there a way to just set all Textures, textureRegions or sprites to be flipped? And by flipped i mean read flipped not actually flip the image "physically" so performance wise about the same.

Comment: I can actually create a texture region by: texture = new TextureRegion(new Texture("badlogic.jpg")); and then just draw it like i always do. Texture region also gives me more options then a regular texture besides flip so i will start using this. Still curious if there is a way to flip every texture without using region.flip on every region.

Comment: @Menno Gouw I believe sprite batch has a [similar method](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/SpriteBatch.html#draw-com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture-float-float-float-float-float-float-float-float-float-int-int-int-int-boolean-boolean-). You might be able to just give your image source inverted height when you draw it, although I am unsure if this would work. I doubt there is much of a performance difference either way.